# Xamarin PostAsync to API being called multiple times and I just want to call it once

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, asynchronous

In my xamarin app i've Properties and Expenses, both on creation make a PostAsync to a API. While Properties PostAsync is called only once, Expenses PostAsync is being called multiple times and i just want it to be called once.

> Here is PostAsync method for Expenses:

```
public async Task<Expense> AddItemAsync(Expense item)
    {           
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/expenses", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

        string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Expense>(responseContent);

        items.Add(item);

        return item;
    }
```

> The Properties PostAsync is exactly the same only changes the type of
>   given argument to Property instead of Expense.
>   Also they are separeted because in future i may make some diferences for them.

Comment: first, please learn to use async/await properly.  Second, if this is being called multiple times then you need to look at the calling code.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jason but do you have any suggestion of properly use for async/await in these case that i might have missed? The calling code starts in a view with a save button which on click uses MessagingCenter to go to the EspensesViewModel and from there it calls the DataStore.PostAsync and awaits. Its done just like in Properties but properties doesn't produces duplicates only Expenses. I believe its because Properties have a attribute unique..

Comment: it is better to `await` every call inside an async method. use like this
`string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: first where did you call this api from ? second i agree with @Nithin

Comment: Thanks NithinChandran and @Mina Fawzy, i'm calling the api from this Xamarin app with the method i stated above, while in debug i watch this method repeat itself some times when multi thread is used. I don't understand why some times multi threading is used and others don't?? When multi thread happens the API is called the number of times the threads pass throw:
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/expenses", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: I mean where did you call this method AddItemAsync ?